# odoo v8 : Facing an error while overriding create() function of mrp.bom

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to override the create() function of mrp.bom and in it i will change the value if a field in product.template , but when i press 'save' i face that error :

```
res = super(bom_override, self).create(vals)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

i searched for the reason and every reason i found i checked my code for it and nothing to slove 
i hope that anyone can help me with that.

here is my code:

```
class bom_override(models.Model):
    _name = 'mrp.bom'
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        product_obj = self.env['product.template'].search([('id','=',vals['product_id'])])
        product_obj.write({'has_bom':True})
        res = super(bom_override, self).create(vals)
        return res
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
class bom_override(models.Model):
_name = 'mrp.bom'
_inherit = 'mrp.bom'

@api.model
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    product_obj = self.env['product.template'].sudo().search_read([('id','=',vals['product_id'])])
    product_obj.write({'has_bom':True})
    res = super(bom_override, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I already tried overriding create() function and it works for me.
This is my code :

```
    class Partner(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'res.partner'
      ....

      @api.model
        def create(self, vals):
          template_obj = self.env['template.partner']
          obj = super(Partner, self).create(vals)
          template_obj.create({
            'local_id' : obj.id,
            'name' : obj.name,
            'update_date' : datetime.now(),
            })
          return obj
```